# "multiple admin login can acces only one at a time.."

Tags: html, reactjs

> i want to implement a feature in app that at a time only one admin can login and if someone else try to login with same admin id  on another device it should give warning and will generate a pop up saying that user already logged in you can not access this account..
>   I hope someone give me the answer how i solve this issue..

here my code...!!

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import firebase from './config/database';
import Config from './config/app';

import * as firebaseCLASS from 'firebase';
require("firebase/firestore");


class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            error: '',
        };

        this.handleChangeUsername = this.handleChangeUsername.bind(this);
        this.handleChangePassword = this.handleChangePassword.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.authenticate = this.authenticate.bind(this);
    }



    handleChangeUsername(event) {
        this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
    }

    handleChangePassword(event) {
        this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        //alert('Username: ' + this.state.username+ " Password: "+this.state.password);
        this.authenticate(this.state.username, this.state.password);
        event.preventDefault();
    }


    authenticate(username, password) {
        const displayError = (error) => {
            this.setState({ error: error });
        }


        if (Config.adminConfig.allowedUsers != null && Config.adminConfig.allowedUsers.indexOf(username) == -1) {
            //Error, this user is not allowed anyway
            displayError("This user doens't have access to this admin panel!");
        } else {
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
                .then(
                function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("Yes, user is logged in");
                }
                )
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // Handle Errors here.
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    console.log(error.message);
                    displayError(error.message);

                });
        }


    }

    authWithGoogle() {
        var provider = new firebaseCLASS.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
            // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            // The signed-in user info.
            var user = result.user;
            // ...
        }).catch(function (error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            var email = error.email;
            // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
            var credential = error.credential;
            console.log(errorMessage);
            // ...
        });
    }

    showGoogleLogin() {
        if (Config.adminConfig.allowedUsers != null && Config.adminConfig.allowedUsers.length > 0 && Config.adminConfig.allowGoogleAuth) {
            return (<div>
                <p className="category text-center">
                    <a onClick={this.authWithGoogle} className="btn btn-social btn-fill btn-google">
                        <i className="fa fa-google"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login with google
            </a>
                </p>
                <br />
                <p className="category text-center">Or login using email</p>
            </div>)
        } else {
            return (<div></div>)
        }
    }

    render() {


        return (

            <div>


                <nav className="navbar navbar-primary navbar-transparent navbar-absolute">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example-2">
                                <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                {Config.adminConfig.appName}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


                                <li className=" active ">
                                    <a>
                                        <i className="material-icons">fingerprint</i>Login
                          </a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div className="wrapper wrapper-full-page">
                    <div className="full-page login-page" data-image="assets/img/lock.jpeg">
                        <div className="content">
                            <div className="container">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3">
                                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                            <div className="card card-login card-hidden">


                                                <div className="card-header text-center" data-background-color="rose">
                                                    <h4 className="card-title">Login</h4>

                                                </div>

                                                <div className="card-content">

                                                    <h4>{this.state.error}</h4>
                                                    <div className="input-group">
                                                        <span className="input-group-addon">
                                                            <i className="material-icons">email</i>
                                                        </span>
                                                        <div className="form-group label-floating">
                                                            <label className="control-label">Email address</label>
                                                            <input type="email" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChangeUsername} className="form-control" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="input-group">
                                                        <span className="input-group-addon">
                                                            <i className="material-icons">lock_outline</i>
                                                        </span>
                                                        <div className="form-group label-floating">
                                                            <label className="control-label">Password</label>
                                                            <input type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChangePassword} className="form-control" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="footer text-center">
                                                    <input type="submit" className="btn btn-rose btn-simple btn-wd btn-lg" value={this.state.login} />

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <footer className="footer">
                            <div className="container">
                                <nav className="pull-left">
                                    <ul>

                                    </ul>
                                </nav>
                                <p className="copyright pull-right">

                                    &copy;
                          <script>
                                        document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
                          </script>
                                    {Config.adminConfig.appName}


                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have some back-end storage to store last time user was online.

Then every *N* seconds do *keep-alive* request to server.

When logging in check if user was last time online before *N* seconds.
If user is currently online - deny access; else allow access and update online status.